# Falha ao carregar imagens no desenvolvimento de um pacote npm

Tags: node.js

Estava desenvolvendo um pacote npm e me deparei com o seguinte erro.

A minha estrutura atual do projeto é a seguinte. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

dentro da minha pasta assets tem umas imagens que eu estou precisando usar para o desenvolvimento do meu pacote, basicamente eu vou pegar essas imagens e retornar um base64 delas.
A classe que retorna o base64 da imagem é o arquivo Base64.png que está dentro de utils.
Base64.js

```
export default class Convert {
    constructor(){
    }

    _getBase64(b){
       return b.toString('base64');
    }

     _convertImageToBase64(b){

        //let path = b == 'Elo' ? '../assets/bandeira_elo.png' : b == 'MasterCard' ? '../assets/bandeira_master_card.png' : '../assets/bandeira_visa.png';
    
        if(fileSystem.statSync(String('../assets/bandeira_master_card.png')).isFile()){
            return Promise.resolve(this._getBase64(fileSystem.readFileSync(path.resolve('../assets/bandeira_master_card.png')).toString('base64'))); 
        }else{
            return {
                success: false,
                error: 'Algo de errado aconteceu', 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Se eu entrar pelo terminal dentro da pasta utils e der um node Base64.js, ele funciona normalmente e retorna o base64 da imagem.
Porem quando eu importo ele para ser usado dentro do arquivo MainPtBr.js e executo a mesma função gera o seguinte erro:

```
  <rejected> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '../assets/bandeira_master_card.png'
      at Object.statSync (node:fs:1142:3)
      at Convert._convertImageToBase64 (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/dist/utils/Base64.js:15:23)
      at MainPTBR._checkBandeiraToImage (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/dist/PT-BR/MainPtBr.js:200:49)
      at _checkBandeiraToImage (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/index.js:30:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/index.js:44:13)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
      at loader (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
      at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14) {
    errno: -2,
    syscall: 'stat',
    code: 'ENOENT',
    path: '../assets/bandeira_master_card.png'
  }
}
node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '../assets/bandeira_master_card.png'
    at Object.statSync (node:fs:1142:3)
    at Convert._convertImageToBase64 (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/dist/utils/Base64.js:15:23)
    at MainPTBR._checkBandeiraToImage (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/dist/PT-BR/MainPtBr.js:200:49)
    at _checkBandeiraToImage (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/index.js:30:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/index.js:44:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at loader (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/user/Documents/Projects/cartao/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'stat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '../assets/bandeira_master_card.png'
}
```

Acredito que para utilizar arquivos dentro da minha lib eu preciso adicionar algo no package.json, tanto para funcionar no meu ambiente de teste e quando eu publicar, funcionara em outros computadores.

Comment: Provavelmente isso ocorre por você estar utilizando caminho relativo. Como está usando `../` ou `./` para resolver o caminho, dependendo de onde é executado, o diretório montado vai estar diferente. Talvez seja o caso de capturar o "diretório base" em uma variável e montar o caminho do arquivo concatenando o mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caminho da sua imagem, utilize a função `path.normalize`:

```
const path = require('path');

...

if (fileSystem.statSync(path.normalize('../assets/bandeira_master_card.png')).isFile()) {

...
```